# Should I delete a heap-allocated string after sending it to std::string?

Tags: c++

Say I have this:

```
char * p = new char[10];
std::string str = p;
```

Do I have to `delete[]` `p` or does `std::string` do that for me?

Comment: `std::string` copies it. Simply don't use `new`.

Comment: Ask yourself this: how would `std::string` know whether it's given a heap-allocated string?  How would it distinguish between what you did and `std::string str = "Hello world!";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to delete[] p or does std::string do that for me?

No it doesn't Generally, each `new` must be paired with a `delete`. So,

```
char * p = new char[10];
/* put something into your buffer */

std::string str = p;
/* some stuff */
delete [] p;
```

But you wouldn't need to do that if you created your array on a stack:

```
{
char p[10];
/* put something into your buffer */

std::string str = p;

// delete [] p; // no delete required
}
```

Comment: The stack alternative is safer. If `std::string` runs out of memory, `delete[]` isn't run, but the stack is cleaned up.

Comment: So i will still be able to use the `std::string` even after i delete the original char array string?

Answer (score 2):

You have to release the memory yourself because `string` will ***copy it by value***, i.e. `str` will allocate a buffer on heap to hold that value.

If `str` would release the memory, what will happen to the following code then?

```
std::string str = "hello, world"; //"hello, world" itself is not on heap
```

Answer (score 1):

No one will manage your memory. every memory you allocate must be freed by you. Some windows APIs return heap allocated results which also must be freed by you. I cannot remember any situation where some other library or API frees my allocated memory.

Comment: Smart pointers will free memory you allocate with new - no delete is correct then.

Comment: @NeilKirk Smart pointers do but they have other cons. No standard windows API use smart pointers by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to delete[] p

Yes.

> or does std::string do that for me?

No.